# Laravel changing view variable with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to make a script that when I click a flag button it will pick up the flag value "en" and replace it in my url and refresh the content without refreshing the page.

So far i have this :

```
                <li class="nav-item dropdown ml-lg-2">
                    <a class="nav-link px-0" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-offset="0,10">
                        <img alt="Português" style="height: 25px;" src="{{URL::asset('/img/flags/pt.svg')}}">
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-sm" x-placement="bottom-start" style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 49px, 0px);">
                        <a href="{{route('user_register', 'pt')}}" class="dropdown-item"><img alt="Português" style="height: 25px;" src="{{URL::asset('/img/flags/pt.svg')}}">Português</a>
                        <a href="{{route('user_register', 'en')}}" class="dropdown-item"><img alt="Inglês" style="height: 25px;" src="{{URL::asset('/img/flags/us.svg')}}">Inglês</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

But i wanted something like this :

```
$('.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-item.en').click((function(event){

    const locale = 'en';

    $.ajax({
        url: RegisterUrl,
        type:"GET",
        data:{
            locale,
        },
        success:function(response){       
            }
        },
    );
}));
```

I just dont know how to switch the locale variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the selected value of the flag to ajax call and in Laravel code load the view as HTML by the following code

```
 $returnHTML = view('job.userjobs')->with('userjobs', $userjobs)->render();
return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'html'=>$returnHTML));
```

Then in response, you may change the inner HTML of your main div with response

```
$('.dropdown-menu a.dropdown-item.en').click((function(event){

const locale = 'en';
   var selectedOptionVal = $('.dropdown-menu').find(":selected").val();//selected option value;
locale=selectedOptionVal;
$.ajax({
    url: RegisterUrl,
    type:"GET",
    data:{
        locale,
    },
    success:function(response){     
if(response.success){
$('#mainDiv').html(response.html);
}
        }
    },
);
}));
```